# Why aren't notifications displayed after setting a custom unique id (Notifee)?

Tags: react-native

I am using Notifee to show notifications and everything works fine. However, if I set a custom identifier in the displayNotification method, the notifications stop appearing. I have to add a unique identifier because if there are multiple notifications on the device, they show incorrect content when opened (content from the very first notification).

Notifee version - 7.1.0

React native version - 0.64.2

Since the issue was only occurring on Android, I decided to add the identifier only on this os, and now the problem is only happening on Android.

```js
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  if (!remoteMessage?.notification) {
    onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
  }
});
```

```js
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid';

const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890');

export const onDisplayNotification = async remoteMessage => {
  const title = remoteMessage?.notification?.title || remoteMessage?.data?.title,
    body = remoteMessage?.notification?.body || remoteMessage?.data?.body,
    data = remoteMessage?.notification?.data || remoteMessage?.data;

  if (!title && !body) return false;

  // Request permissions (required for iOS)
  await notifee.requestPermission();
  // Create a channel (required for Android)
  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id: 'default',
    name: 'Default Channel',
    importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    sound: 'default'
  });

  await notifee.displayNotification({
    ...(Platform.OS === 'android' ? { id: nanoid() } : null),
    title,
    body,
    data,
    android: {
      channelId,
      // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
      pressAction: {
        id: 'default'
      }
    }
  });
  return true;
};
```